# Implementing z-axis in a 2D side-scroller

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, isometric

I'm making a side scroller similar to Castle Crashers and right now I'm using SAT for collision detection. That works great, but I want to simulate level "depth" by allowing objects to move up and down on the screen, basically along a z-axis (like this screenshot http://favoniangamers.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/castle-crashers-ps3.jpg). This isn't an isometric game, but rather uses parallax scrolling.

I added a z component to my vector class, and I plan to cull collisions based on the 'thickness' of a shape and it's z position. I'm just not sure how calculate the positions of shapes for rendering or how to add jumping with gravity. How do I calculate the max y value (for the ground) as the z position changes? Basically it's the relationship of the z and y axis that confuses me.

I'd appreciate links to resources if anyone knows of this topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's actually possible to make your collision detection algorithm dimensionally agnostic. Just have a collision detector that works along one dimension, use that to check each dimension, and your answer to "are these colliding or not" is the logical AND of the collision detection along each of the dimensions.
2. Your game should be organised to keep the interaction of game objects, and the rendering of the game to the screen completely seperate. You can think of these two sections of the program as the "model" and the "view". In the model, you have a full 3D world, with 3 axes. You can't go halvesies on this point without some level of pain. Your model must be proper 3D.

The view will read the location of all the game objects, and project them onto the screen using the camera definition. For this part you don't need a full 3D rendering engine. The correct technical term for the perspective you're talking about is "oblique", and it can be seen in many ancient chinese and japanese scroll paintings and prints- in particular look for images of "The Tale of Genji".

The on screen position of an object (including the ground surface!) goes something like this:

```
DEPTH_RATIO=0.5;
view_x=model_x-model_z*DEPTH_RATIO-camera_x;
view_y=model_y+model_z*DEPTH_RATIO-camera_y;
```

you can modify for a straight orthographic front projection:

```
DEPTH_RATIO=0.5;
view_x=model_x-camera_x;
view_y=model_y+model_z*DEPTH_RATIO-camera_y;
```

And of course don't forget to cull objects outside the volume defined by the camera.

You can also use this mechanism to handle the positioning of parallax layers for you. This is of course, a matter changing your camera to a 1-point perspective projection instead of an orthographic projection. You don't have to use this to change the rendered size of your sprites, but it will help you manage the x position of objects realistically. if you're up for a challenge, you could even mix projections- use 1 point perspective for deep backgrounds, and the orthographic stuff for the foreground.

Comment: Great answer Breton. I have it all worked out now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should separate your conceptual Y axis used by you physics calculation (collision detection etc.) and the Y axis you actually draw on the screen. That way it becomes less confusing.

Just do calculations per normal pretending there is no relationship between Y and Z axis then when you actually draw the object on the screen you simulate the Z axis using the Y axis:

```
screen_Y = Y + Z/some_fudge_factor;
```

Actually, this is how real 3d engines work. After all the world calculations are done the X, Y and Z coordinates are mapped onto screen_X and screen_Y via a function (usually a bit more complicated than the equation above, but just a bit).

For example, to implement pseudo-isormetric view in your game you can even apply Z to the screen_X axis so objects are displaced diagonally instead of vertically.

Comment: Added further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks slebetman, I was definitely confusing the drawing with the collision simulation.